# Random variable independent of its own sign.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be any random variable and assume $X$ is independent of $\text{sgn}(X)$. 
What is known about $X$ in this case? I'm guessing its equivalent to symmetry, but I haven't  had luck proving it.

Comment: If $X$ and $ \text{sign}(X)$ are independent then $\mathbb E [ X \vert \text{sign}(X)=1] = \mathbb E [ X \vert \text{sign}(X)=-1]$ (assuming that the events $\text{sign}(X)=1$ and $\text{sign}(X)=-1$ have non zero probability). The former is clearly $\geq 0$ while the latter is clearly $\leq 0$.

Comment: I suspect the user meant to ask the more usual problem of when |X| and sgn(X) are independent.

Answer (score 2):

No, if $X$ and sgn$(X)$ are independent then the distribution of $X$ is necessarily not symmetric around zero. The only way to achieve this is if sgn$(X)$ is a.s. constant, i.e. $X$ is a.s. positive, a.s. negative, or a.s. zero.

Answer (score 1):

By the assumption, 
$$P(X>0)=P(X>0,\operatorname{sgn}(X)=+1)=P(X>0)P(\operatorname{sgn}(X)=+1)=P(X>0)^2$$ 
so that $P(X>0)\in\{0,1\}$. Likewise $P(X<0)\in\{0,1\}$ and $P(0)\in\{0,1\}$. In other words, $\operatorname{sgn}(X)$ is a.s. constant (as already pointed out by Joris). In the other direction, for any distribution with $\operatorname{sgn}(X)$ is a.s. constant we have independance trivially. Except for the case $X=0$ a.s., such random variables are *not* symmetric.